# How do I blog my favorite Arduino code to Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

I have a favorite Arduino program that I want to keep for the future. Can I put it on Stack Overflow so I can find it (if I lose it). Plus, someone might learn from it.

Comment: Nope. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions and answers. You may be looking for http://github.com

Comment: If you can make it a (good) question and an answer then [you're welcome to post a question and answer it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) simultaneously.

Comment: Why is it not already under version control?

Answer (score 9):

No, you can not, at least not based on the limited info in your question.

Stack Overflow has the model of a question and answers. Period. All submission need to follow that format.

Additionally the questions needs to be [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [well asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to meet the quality attributes this community adheres.

If you're able to formulate a good and on-topic question and answer as well you could consider a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Not following the community consensus could lead to down votes, close votes and even deletion of your question.

Based on your current suggestion it looks like you want to advertise or keep a backup of your favorite programming tool. I don't expect that to be well received. You better find a different venue to post that. Maybe check if Quora or Reddit can have that or go for GitHub.

Answer (score 8):

No, Stack Overflow is not the place for that.  We expect posts to follow the question-answer format. You could put your code on https://gist.github.com/.